# Extended navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have activity, lets call it TestActivity. This TestActivity extends Activity that has navigation drawer. In TestActivity I would like to change the NavigationDrawerToggle and replace it with up arrow.

```
public class Test extends DashboardActivity {

    private DrawerLayout navDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Dashboard activity is kinda long and I have some more stuff there, but basicaly it follows this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have one `Activity` that utilizes the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and another that still uses the `DrawerLayout`, but without the toggle. And in that case, the easiest way for you to do that is to have two "base" classes. Here's an example.

**1) An `Activity` that implements the `DrawerLayout`**

```
public class BaseDrawerActivity extends Activity {

    protected DrawerLayout mDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_drawer_layout);

        mDrawer = ...
    }

}
```

**2) An `Activity` that implements the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`**

```
public class BaseDrawerToggleActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle = ...
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

When you want to use the `DrawerLayout` **without** the toggle, subclass `BaseDrawerActivity` and when you want to use an `Activity` **with** the toggle, subclass `BaseDrawerToggleActivity`. So, your `TestActivity` would look like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```